# Python Pandas Data Cleaning Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read large log files, which has been parsed using different delimiters (legacy issue). Each file is 100s of MB, and there are 1000s of files. There is a lot of junk, non-ascii characters, long lines in these logs. Basically, expect anything and everything in the files.

**Question: How do I avoid these multiple issues, & make the code fool proof**

```
    pandas.errors.ParserError: '
    ' expected after '"'

    pandas.errors.ParserError: field larger than field limit (131072)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 75.8 MiB for an array with shape (4968252,) and data type complex128
```

**Code:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None)    
df = df[0].str.strip().str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'})
```

Comment: does `dtype='str'` in `read_csv` help?

Comment: you should also examine this file for missing or mixed line separators (i.e. '\r\n' and '\n' in one file), in case of mixed line separators you may try `sep=chr(0)` or any other char that is guaranteed to not be present in the file.

Comment: @Stef: `dtype='str'` didnt help. the log-file may have unix line-separators or windows line-separators. it will not have both

Comment: Hmm, then I'm afraid that I don't have any other idea without seeing the actual data.

Comment: Stef: after a lot of troubleshooting, i was able to pin-point the issue. If the datafile has **'chr0'** anywhere, the script starts throwing various errors. These errors differ depending on if **'chr0'** is present in the email field or if in the data field. This is if i change the code to:  `df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='chr(0)', header=None, engine='python', dtype='str')`

Comment: Stef: do pls help!

Comment: maybe you could preprocess the file to remove the null characters (`tr -d '\000' < myFile.log > myFile.no0.log`)

Comment: Thanks Stef. That wont be efficient. Could you review a followup issue. If I can solve this, then issue is mitigated -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358983/python-pandas-quotation-marks

Comment: is this issue resolved with the followup issue or does it still exist indenpendently of the other one?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up the data themselves is in my experience the only robust way. This is only my personal opinion, but writing a piece of code that covers all eventualities without looking at the data first is practically impossible

Probably perl, bash or plain string manipulation in python would be useful tools to automatize some preprocessing. Otherwise you could try to reverse engineer how the files where written in different legacy versions and have a reader function for each of these. If they are internally consistent that is.

Also you might want to look at dask. Its ability to support wildcards in the csv-filenames might come in handy.