# Python Pandas Quotation Marks

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a large log file on pandas, but this file is not uniform. There is legacy and junk. Before I load the data on pandas, can I remove the first character of the row, if it is a quotation marks (")?

I am aware I could pre-clean the data before adding it to PD. However, that seems like an inefficient way. I would rater do it using pandas

**Code:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, engine='python', chunksize=10000)
df = df[0].str.strip().str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'})
print(df)
```

**Data:**

```
"email1@foo.com:datahere2    :  this row will throw an error
email2@foo.com:datahere2
email3@foo.com:datahere2
```

Comment: Is your question: how to improve the `str.split` operation? In that case, could you show a few typical elements of `df[0]` before the string operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read_csv` with `QUOTE_NONE` (`3`) and then strip the quotation marks:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, engine='python', quoting=3)
df = df[0].str.strip(' \t"').str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'})
```

Comment: Stef:  One last question plz. the ccode works now. The only trouble is that if the input file is too large, the script throws a error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 75.8 MiB for an array`. If i split the file and try again, it works. So, is it possible to ask DF to load the data in chunks?

Comment: yes, you can specify `chunksize`, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) for details

Comment: Stef: can you check my code pls (I have edited my original ques). does this look correct, to read the full data?

Comment: Stef:  this will explain plz. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362251/python-pandas-import-large-files