# Python Pandas Import Large Files

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code to load various log files, and then process them later in the code. This code works perfectly, unless the log file is large in size. I know there isn't any other issue, because if manually I split the large-log file into smaller files, then the code works again, without any issues.

So, what's the best way out? Is it better to write some code before pandas, to split large files? Or can pandas import large files (in chunks?) but still let me process it.

**code:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    for file in files:  
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, engine='python', quoting=3)
            df = df[0].str.strip(' \t"').str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'})
```

**error:**

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 75.8 MiB for an array with shape (4968252,) and data
```

Comment: I guess `pd.read_csv` has a parameter like `chunksize`. You might want to look into it.

Comment: [Iterating through files chunk by chunk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) from pandas docs.

Comment: If you have columns of numeric data, pandas defaults to int64 or float64. Consider specifying the dtype to int/float 32 during read, to reduce the memory usage. Will depend on your data range.

Comment: data is all strings (not integer/float). could anyone help with the code?